# One procedure exec multiple queries one time SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

Here is the thing.
I have a rule table, which include some rules I will run.
And now I need a procedure to run all the rules one time AND I can't pass the RuleId.

The Rule table like:
RuleId
RuleDescription
RuleSqlQuery

And all the query return the same records (Id, Name, Others)

So how do I create a procedure.

Comment: What have you tried so far? From the question, it seems you did not even try to create it...

Comment: I created a output table, rule table. I can create procedure when I can select one rule. But how to union all the rules one time

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sql server, perhaps something like this...

```
create procedure runrules

as

declare @temp table (id int identity(1,1), ruleid int)
declare @curid int
declare @maxid int
declare @tempsql nvarchar(max)

insert into @temp select ruleid from rule

select @curid = 1, @maxid = max(id) from @temp

while @curid <= @maxid
begin

    select @tempsql = RuleSqlQuery 
    from rule R
    inner join @temp T on T.ruleid = R.ruleid
    where T.id = @curid

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @tempsql

    set @curid = @curid + 1
end
```